# How to let my Date-Input look more native?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a Angular/Ionic App and wanted to add a Date:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="value" ng-model="data.reading">
<input type="date" ng-model="data.date">
```

On the iPhone it looks like:
[image]

Is there a way to let it look more native? Because this is just very very ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to install http://ngcordova.com and use the DatePicker plugin that comes with it.